# How to display the int or char into a TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I want to process the comment input and write back into a TextView.
I did a Class named PandaAssistents

```
package panda.com.db;

public class PandaAssistents{

    private static int CallOfIndex;
    private static String comment;
    public PandaAssistents(String input){
        this.comment = input;
        this.CallOfIndex=input.indexOf("熊貓");
    }

    public char getCall(){
        return comment.charAt(CallOfIndex);
    }
}
```

But when I field in a EditText and click a button, it generate an error.

```
private void btnAction(Button btn){
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText edt = (EditText)IndexActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                TextView txt = (TextView)IndexActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                pa = new PandaAssistents(edt.getText().toString());
                txt.setText(pa.getCall());
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't know what the problem is

Comment: try using txt.setText(pa.getCall()+"");

Comment: Can you specify which error??

Comment: to Shashank Kadne: it's runtime error, the program just stop

Comment: Please post the error shown in LogCat.

Comment: to Hiral: it works. Why?

Comment: see my answer, you would get why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextView or EditText's setText requires charsequence or resource id as input parameter, if you want to set char or int, convert to it string before setting into textview. so you can try following:

```
txt.setText(""+pa.getCall());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `this.CallOfIndex=input.indexOf("熊貓")` actually returns a valid index and not -1?  Since you are not error checking this value, if the result is -1, when you call `comment.charAt(CallOfIndex)` with `CallOfIndex` being -1, you will get an [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)